# Gimp - How to loop a gif seamlessly?

Tags: gimp, animation, gif

[image: sailor moon profile edit]

So I'm new at editing and I'm trying to insert gifs but somehow it always ends up with a gap after the gif ends and looks weird, I have no idea how can I change that :/
can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

A few of the frames (that's the layers in GIMP, they play from the bottom of the layer stack upwards) in the image got nothing at the animated locations initially.

I do not know how you intend this animation to run, but I assume the following:

To avoid a gap at the beginning, you should merge the first two frames of each animated area with the background layer - the one with the cutouts. To do that, change their order in the layers dialog to have these animated parts just above the background and merge down

For the remainder, you will probably want to merge the corresponding frames of the upper and lower part into one - again, change their order so that one is above the other in the layers dialog (doesn't matter which one is above - and then merge down.

You can use the Animation Playback filter in GIMP to run the animation and go through it in single steps:

[Filters → Animation → Playback](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-animationplay.html)

Comment: I wanted to have both gifs run independently of each other. Instead the small one below waits until the one above ends to start again

Comment: This is one single GIF file. If you want to have then independent of each other, then you will have to do the compositing - the placement of the images relative to each other - in some other medium. If this is supposed to be presented in a web page, this medium would be the surrounding HTML, and you would have three image files - the background with its cutouts, and two GIF files, one for the upper and one for the lower animation.